# If $A=PU$ and $B=QV$ , $P$ and $Q$ are unitarily similar then $A$ and $B$ are unitarily similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in M_n$

- $A=PU$ and $B=QV$
- $P$ and $Q$ are positive semidefinite.
- $U$ and $V$ are unitary.
- $P$ and $Q$ are unitarily similar.

Can we prove that $A$ and $B$ are  unitarily similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not true..

take $P=Q=I,U=I,V=-I$, Then $A=I,B=-I$, which are not similar.